# In I2C communication, let's assume 10 bytes are to be transferred from Master to slave. What happens if NACK is received after transfer of 5 bytes?

Tags: microcontroller, i2c

Is only erroneous byte sent again and communication resumes or communication is restarted? Similarly, what will happen if data is being received by master?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the I2C specification, if the controller as transmitter sees a NACK during transmission, that means the receiver has either received the byte correctly but can't accept new bytes, or not received the byte (for some of multiple reasons), and the controller must generate either a STOP condition or a repeated START condition to start a new transfer. It is up to the devices what they mean by sending a NACK, and how they then continue communicating, for example ot might just signal that a FIFO is full or it might mean a connector to a sensor is unplugged.

For the second case, if the data is transferred from transmitter device back to host, so it is the host who must send ACK or NACK after each byte, and if host sends a ACK, it means it expects a next byte from device so it should prepare transmitting next byte, and if it receives a NACK, it means host has now transferred the last byte it wants, so the device knows there is no need to transfer anything more and it will stop driving the bus, and maybe ignore clocks and wait for a STOP or START condition.

Answer (score 2):

The communication ends: the master write message is terminated by the target device after a successful write of 5 bytes.

The I2C protocol does not implement retries. Higher level master devices can implement that as the particular system design sees fit. That's typically in software but may be in hardware, such as in a PLD.